# Need assistance with a SQL query to find movies

Tags: sql

I need help with a SQL query: how can I find a list of all languages for which more than 4 films have been translated and in which a particular actor (e.g. Arnold Schwarzenegger) played?

- actor (actor_id, first_name, last_name)
- director (director_id, first_name, last_name)
- film (film_id, title, release_year, language_id, film_length, director_id, country_name)
- film_actor (actor_id, film_id)
- language ( language_id, name)
- film_translation (film_id, language_id)

Comment: What have you tried and found to not work? This post shows no effort or research on your part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
SELECT l.language_id, l.name, COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    film_translation ft 
    INNER JOIn [language] l ON ft.language_id = l.language_id
    INNER JOIN [film] f on ft.film_id = f.film_id
    INNER JOIN [film_actor] fa on f.film_id = fa.film_id
    INNER JOIN [actor] a on fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
WHERE 
    a.first_name ='Arnold'
    and a.last_name  ='Schwarzenegger'
GROUP BY 
    l.language_id, l.name
HAVING 
    COUNT(f.film_id) > 4
```